# Service Fabric local cluster creates 8 GB file when the cluster starts

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

The file in question is **replicatorshared.log**, and it is the largest single file on my machine, even larger than the Windows 10 swap file. I can stop the cluster and delete the file, and it will be created again when the cluster starts.

- Can I control the initial size of this file?
- What is this file used for that it needs to be so large at the outset?

Answer (score 6):

Check out this doc for more info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-configuration

The setting you are interested in modifying is SharedLogSizeInMB.

See also: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/138

Depending on your environment the config will look like this:

```
<Section Name="KtlLogger"> 
    <Parameter Name="SharedLogSizeInMB" Value="4096"/>
</Section>
```

or this:

```
"fabricSettings": [
  {
    "name": "KtlLogger",
    "parameters": [
      {
          "name": "SharedLogSizeInMB",
          "value": "4096"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: These settings are in the cluster manifest file.  My service fabric project doesn't have a cluster manifest file.  Can I make a similar change in the application manifest file?