# In Service Fabric, how do I configure the size of the Replicator Log?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to build and run a Service Fabric application.  I'm getting an error that says

```
Error event: SourceId='System.FM', Property='State'.
Partition is below target replica or instance count.
```

I've read in a few places ([here](https://sahebg.github.io/computersceince/how-to-change-azure-service-fabric-replicator-log-size-drive/)) ([here](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/138)) that I need to configure the replicator log to be smaller.  The [steps to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261300/service-fabric-local-cluster-creates-8-gb-file-when-the-cluster-starts) involve a setting in the cluster manifest file.  I can't find a cluster manifest file in my project.

Is there a way to do this in the application manifest file?

Comment: Is this a cluster in Azure?  Or your local dev cluster (OneBox)?

Comment: @PatrickSteele, I'm running this through Visual Studio, so I think it's a local dev cluster?

Comment: Re-read your [first link](https://sahebg.github.io/computersceince/how-to-change-azure-service-fabric-replicator-log-size-drive/). It shows how to edit a json file which is used to generate the ClusterConfig.xml during cluster creation.

Comment: @PatrickSteele, I don't have any cluster manifest files though, so I don't think I've created any clusters.  Or no cluster manifest files are being created.

Comment: If you're running locally, you have a local DEV cluster. It usually resides in `C:\SfDevCluster`, but it can be moved.  Check there and see if there's a `ClusterManifest.xml` there (but remember, according to the article you linked to, this file is built from the json templates).

Comment: @PatrickSteele, that explains why I couldn't find the file.  I'll take a look at this.  Thanks!